# jquery drag drop hangs or gets stuck for android browser

Tags: android, jquery, drag-and-drop, fabricjs, chromium

see below link 
http://liveweave.com/JckSgC

when I try to drag drop items item gets stuck somewhere on mobile screen without being dropped to droppable area,

and when I click somewhere and screen it starts working (this basically happened once I open page for first time)

what could be the issue and how do I resolve it?

below is code

### js code

```
(function () {
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    var canvas_el = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('canvas1');

    var group;
    fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
        var img1 = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
            var img2 = img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            group = new fabric.Group([img1, img2], {
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            canvas.add(group)
        });
    });


    fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
        var img1 = img.set({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        fabric.Image.fromURL('img/blank.png', function (img) {
            var img2 = img.set({
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            group1 = new fabric.Group([img1, img2], {
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            });
            canvas1.add(group1)
        });
    });



    $(document).ready(function () {



        /* Define drag and drop zones */
        var $drop = $('#canvas-drop-area,#canvas-drop-area1'),
            $gallery = $('td > #image-list li'),
            $draggedImage=null;

        /* Define the draggable properties */
        $gallery.draggable({
             helper: 'clone',
            start: function (e) {
            $draggedImage=event.target;
                $drop.css({
                    'display': 'block'
                })
            },
            stop: function () {
                $(this).find('img').css({
                   /* 'opacity': 0.4 */
                });
                $drop.css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
                $draggedImage=null;
            },
            revert: true
        });

        /* Define the events for droppable properties */
        $drop.droppable({
            over: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var image =$draggedImage&& $draggedImage.src;
                console.log($draggedImage.alt);
                img_to_canvas(image,$draggedImage.alt,$(event.target).is("#canvas-drop-area")?1:2);
            },
            out: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            },
            deactivate: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }
        });

    });


    var img_to_canvas = function(image,sendfront,checkcanvas) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = image;
        if(checkcanvas =='1'){
            if(sendfront=='top'){
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group.item(0).setElement(img);
                        canvas.renderAll();
                }); 
            }else{
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group.item(1).setElement(img);
                        canvas.renderAll();
                }); 
            }
            canvas.calcOffset();  
        }else{
            if(sendfront=='top'){
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group1.item(0).setElement(img);
                        canvas1.renderAll();
                });         
            }else{
                fabric.util.loadImage(img.src, function (img) {
                    group1.item(1).setElement(img);
                        canvas1.renderAll();
                }); 
            }
            canvas1.calcOffset();       
        }

    }


})();
```

Comment: In web browser on PC have ample memory to process data and events, whereas this story upsides down on mobile browsers, as far as android is concerned Android OS kill memory seeking process and threads. Now your problem depends on many slabs, 1. is your device have good memory like 2 or 3 GB ?. 2. Does your mobile device supports Hardware Acceleration ?. 3. How many apps already running on your mobile device.

Comment: Please provide the code in question itself...

Comment: The jquery drag and drop functionality requires lot of RAM and processing as while dragging, it is storing the complete object in memory and do a lot of calculations for each movement. So the drag and drop works perfectly on systems and it also works on high end devices and one more thing not all the mobile browsers cater the drag and drop functionality.

Comment: what to do solve above issue ??

Comment: I have the exact same problem :/... though it works sometimes... but every once in a while, it starts behaving just like you described. Restarting the browser removes the issue temporarily, with me (reloading the page doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JQuery try using the following javascript library called touchpunch and make sure you include it after you include JQuery.

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

I remember having a lot of issues with a drag and drop application while testing on mobile devices until I started using touchpunch.